# R plotly orca Error: No mapbox access token found

Tags: r, docker, electron, r-plotly, orca

I read tutorial https://github.com/plotly/orca#installation and run commands in docker image:

```
apt-get install -y curl && \
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash - && \
apt-get install -y nodejs libgconf-2-4 libgtk2.0-0 && \
npm install -g electron@1.8.4 orca --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

OS details:

```
root@8a17254aeb9a:/# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.6 (stretch)
Release:    9.6
Codename:   stretch
```

but nothing happens when I execute:

```
root@8a17254aeb9a:/# which orca
/usr/bin/orca
root@8a17254aeb9a:/# orca
root@8a17254aeb9a:/# orca --help
root@8a17254aeb9a:/# electron
root@8a17254aeb9a:/# electron -v
```

and when I execute example R code I get error:

```
> library(plotly)
> p <- plot_ly(z = ~volcano) %>% add_surface()
> orca(p, "surface-plot.svg")
Error: No mapbox access token found. Obtain a token here
https://www.mapbox.com/help/create-api-access-token/
Once you have a token, assign it to an environment variable 
named 'MAPBOX_TOKEN', for example,
Sys.setenv('MAPBOX_TOKEN' = 'secret token')
```

I read a lot of tutorials and issues, but still have no answer. Can you help?

Comment: Where in your code do you set the mapbox access token?

Comment: Nowhere. Do I really need some tokens to generate simple image from plot?

Comment: That's what it's telling you.

Comment: but why `orca --help` doesn't print anything as in example one github?

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the installation instructions and have a command-line `orca` as specified, then the problem with the *"No mapbox access token found"* can be solved by assigning a random number:

```
library(plotly)
Sys.setenv(MAPBOX_TOKEN = 11122223333444) # it doesn't matter what number I put!

p <- plot_ly(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, color = 1:10)
orca(p, format = "svg", "plot.svg")
```

This worked for storing locally high quality images using `plotly (4.8.0)` and `orca (1.2.1-1)`.

P.S.: If you install **the latest version of plotly** (I tested it with `4.8.9000`) then it works without setting a random mapbox token. Install the latest plotly with: `devtools::install_github('ropensci/plotly')`